# Unity - ensure that only one instance does the given command

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, initialization

I have some texts whom I want to copy the content of another one.
For this I get all the instances of these *copycat* texts in the `Start()` function. However, I need to do this only once. To make this compact, I don't wish to do this in my *Singleton `GameManager`*, so I use a `static bool` that is changed when I do this initialization like so:

```
 #region Variables
    //using this so that we get the references of the texts only once.
    static bool _initDone = false;
    CopyText[] scripts;
    static Text[] texts;
    #endregion
    void Start()
    {
        #region What to do
        /*
         * Getting all this script's gameobjects, and their texts.
         * note that this scripts is attached only to objects with Text attribute.
         * after that nullifying the CopyText array to save space. 
        */
        #endregion
        if (!_initDone)
        {
            //so only the first one of this instance will do it.
            _initDone = true;
            scripts = Object.FindObjectsOfType<CopyText>();
            for (int i = 0; i < scripts.Length; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    texts[i] = scripts[i].GetComponent<Text>();
                }
                catch
                {
                    //in case it is put on an object that doesn't have a Text
                    Destroy(scripts[i]);
                }

            }
            scripts = null; 
            //by now we should have our references of all copycat texts.
        }
    }
```

This *should* work but I have no notion if two instances will run at the same time and both of them will do this magic. Is there a way to ensure that the `Start()` function runs only on **one** instance of these copycat texts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All `Start` methods will run sequentially, Unity has a main thread that runs all the methods sequentially. If you don't modify that variable from an other thread manually started, it won't have any problem.

Given that it is a static variable all instances will have access, and it will only exist once. I don't know if this is a good design approach, but it will work.

Just for ordering stuff I would separate that code in a static method and call it maybe `InitTexts`.

Comment: So you say I should put that stuff in a `static` method, call it in one of my `Start()` functions the same was as it is now?

Comment: Yes, your code will work, just to be a little tidier I would move it to a static method and call it from `Start()`.

Comment: Did just that and yes, it works. Thanks for your help.